# How to display value from scope function(defined in main function) to HTML Page?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="FlowChartController">
 {{myText1}}

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('FlowChartController', function($scope) {
  $scope.click=function(){  $scope.myText1 = "myText1";}
});
</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here I am unable to access myText1 variable as it is defined inside click function. If I put same myText1 variable outside click function, I am able to access it.

Comment: You can call something on initialization $scope.click(1,"Raj");

Comment: Hey Value has been passed to click function from some other JS file. I have problem with updating same value to "HTML page". I.e I have value stored in "myText1"

Comment: How did you pass value from another js file? Are you using another controller that has the same value?

Comment: Yeah, It has been passed from someother Javascript file.

Comment: I just reformat your answer. Will I was reformating it, it had to fix some syntaxes error. Can you please try this in the right context with the myApp instanciated?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to call the click function:

```
         $scope.click = function (id,name) {
    $scope.myText1=name;
    alert(this.myText1);
            }; 
$scope.click(1,samplename);
```

Thne it automatically works!

Comment: Hey Dinesh, Value has been passed to click function from someother JS file.Value is stored in "MyText1" variable but I have problem with updating same value to "HTML page".

Comment: Is that html page which is calling the function using the same controller where you defined the function? If not please work it out in same js file then only it will update... But if u want to use two different js files then you can use $broadcast and $on  to update value check the link: http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/5d8be0b6-e294-457e-82b0-ba7cc10cae0e.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to call function in Html:

```
<button ng-Clike="click(1,"feras")" />
```

and You can View the Name in Html :

```
<p> {{myText1}} </p>
```

Or You can Edit the **JsFile** To :

```
$scope.click = function (id,name) {
$scope.myText1=name;
alert(this.myText1);
};

$scope.click(1,"feras");
```

Comment: Sir, Value has been passed from someother JS file. Forget about name variable. Suppose $scope.myText1="Hii" is defined inside click function which I want to show in HTML page.

Comment: Yes you should to defined inside click function.

Comment: But I am still not able to get value of "myText1". If we declare same thing outside click function then I am able to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="FlowChartController">
 {{text}}

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('FlowChartController', function($scope) {
    $scope.text = "myText1";
});
</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah it works fine if you decalre inside main function. But Here I have declared variable inside another scope function.